# Android: AudioRecord Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object

Tags: android, avaudiorecorder, android-audiorecord

Android: I want to read buffers from mic so that i can perform process on it, Following is my code

```
int sampleRateInHz = 8000;// 44100, 22050 and 11025
        int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

        //int bufferSize =11025 + 
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz,channelConfig, audioFormat);


        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRateInHz,channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

        if(audioRecord.getState()== AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            Log.e("recording", "before");


            boolean flag = true;
            while (flag) {
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            audioRecord.release();
        }
        Log.e("recording", "stopeed");


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

I get following error every time i try to test the program

06-04 00:18:17.222: E/AudioRecord-Java(488): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO is depreciated and you should use instead CHANNEL_IN_MONO when reading into the buffer. I had a similar problem with instantiating the AudioRecord object and this turned out to be the solution for me.

Comment: My api level is 7 and in api 7 there is no CHANNEL_IN_MONO only CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO

Comment: I was using api level 3 android platform 1.5 thats what the problem was i upgraded api level to api level 7 which is platform 2.1 and it fixed. I also changed from CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO  to CHANNEL_IN_MONO. I also noticed that api level 3 in emulator there is no property for audio recording. thanks for great help.

Answer (score 7):

This exception is also raised if

1. audio recording is already in progress or
2. recording is not available or
3. App does not have proper permission ex: App does not have record permission etc

Comment: The third suggestion is important here, since the error isn't descriptive at all. For anyone else out there, just add this to your manifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

Comment: Just for Android newcomers, when targetApi >= 23, you need to grant permission in runtime. check out [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 1):

A may be this can be answer?:

Params:

audioSource – the recording source. See MediaRecorder.AudioSource for the recording source definitions.

sampleRateInHz – the sample rate expressed in Hertz. **44100Hz is currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices**, but other rates such as 22050, 16000, and 11025 may work on some devices.

AudioFormat.SAMPLE_RATE_UNSPECIFIED means to use a route-dependent value which is usually the sample rate of the source. getSampleRate() can be used to retrieve the actual sample rate chosen.

channelConfig – describes the configuration of the audio channels. See
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO and AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO. AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO is guaranteed to work on all devices.

audioFormat – the format in which the audio data is to be returned. See AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, and AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT.

bufferSizeInBytes – the total size (in bytes) of the buffer where audio data is written to during the recording. New audio data can be read from this buffer in smaller chunks than this size. See getMinBufferSize(int, int, int) to determine the minimum required buffer size for the successful creation of an AudioRecord instance.
**Using values smaller than getMinBufferSize() will result in an initialization failure.**